# Copy IP address in buffer

Tags: c, pointers, network-programming, ip

I'm building a firewall in C and I have the following problem. I ask for an IP address in the client side and I get 4 numbers (the octets of the IP address in a dotted quad format).
Like in this example:

```
255.255.197.0
```

I get this 4 octets in **Integer** type data. To copy this into a buffer of **Characters** I use the **`sprintf()`** function, but I get a segmentation error.

```
char buffer[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];            // The buffer to save the IP address
bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));    // Clean the buffer

// Gets the address
int o1, o2, o3, o4;
do
{ 
  printf("Introduce the 4 octets of the IP address (dotted quad format).\n");
  printf("Numbers must go from 0 to 255.\n\n");

  valid = TRUE;
  printf("Introduce first octet (X.-.-.-): ");
  scanf("%d", &o1);
  printf("Introduce second octet (-.X.-.-): ");
  scanf("%d", &o2);
  printf("Introduce third octet (-.-.X.-): ");
  scanf("%d", &o3);
  printf("Introduce fourth octet (-.-.-.X): ");
  scanf("%d", &o4);
  if (o1 < 0 || o1 > 255 || o2 < 0 || o2 > 255 || o3 < 0 || o3 > 255 || o4 < 0 || o4 > 255)
  {
    printf("Error [Client]: Invalid number.\n");
    valid = FALSE;
  }
} while (valid == FALSE);

// When octets are valid
sprintf(buffer, "%d.%d.%d.%d", o1, o2, o3, o4); // Copy the address in String format in buffer
inet_aton(buffer, &my_rule.addr);
printf("The IP address is %s\n", my_rule.addr);
```

`o1`, `o2`, `o3` and `o4` are the 4 octets of the address. Any idea of how I can put this integers into the `char` buffer?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], now your code is incomplete and it’s impossible to say what exactly is wrong

Comment: Well, in between I do some scanf to get the o1, o2, o3 and o4 values. Now I edit the code.

Comment: `bzero` is deprecated, use `memset`.  What is `MAX_BUFF_SIZE`?

Comment: Oh! Didn't know that thanks!! MAX_BUFF_SIZE is 1024 bytes.

Comment: "*I get a segmentation error.*" in exactly which line?

Comment: As alk points out, your print statement at the bottom, assuming `my_rule.addr` is of type `struct addr_in`, is wrong.  Your compiler should be spitting out a warning about that.  Always pay attention to what your compiler is telling you.  I like to turn up the warning levels with `-Wall -Wpedantic`, and it can also help to treat warnings like errors with `-Werror` to keep you from successfully compiling until all warnings are handled.

Comment: You have to make sure you have correct data type when you print. String in C is terminated with null character.

Answer (score 3):

This does not make sense:

```
  printf("The IP address is %s\n", my_rule.addr);
```

The `s` conversion specifier expects the address of the 1st element of a `0`-terminate `char`-array, a C-"string".

The code (most likely, as you do not show it) passes a `struct in_addr`.

The compiler should have warned you about this.

---

And BTW, you are aware that `255.255.197.0`  is *not* a valid IP-address, are you?

Comment: Yeah you're right! I forgot to put `my_rule.addr.s_addr` thanks!
Also the IP is an example as I said above, I didn't even search it.

Comment: @GuimGonzalez: Trying to printf `my_rule.addr.s_addr` as a C-string would fail as well.